# How to Deactivate a project?

Tags: tfs

Is there a way to deactivate a project in TFS? (not delete, just deactivate so nobody can checkout or checkin)

This is more of a precaution rather than a hard enforcement. We have a project that was branched but was recently merged to a trunk. This project is no longer in use and I don't want anyone to accidentally use it by checking in/out any of its content. It will eventually be deleted when we have tested the merge completely

Comment: You could remove permissions to that project....

Comment: We're all administrators

Comment: So if you are all admins even if there was a deactivate project feature, wouldn't they be able to reactivate it and do whatever they wanted anyway?

Comment: Project Admins or TFS Admins (i.e. server admins) ?

Comment: Should not allow everyone to be project admins.

Comment: This is more of a precaution rather than a hard enforcement. We have a project that was branched but was recently merged to a trunk. This project is no longer in use and I don't want anyone to accidentally use it. It will eventually be deleted when we have tested the merge completely.

Comment: @Amissico -- We're a small organization - this is not about security.

Comment: @Amissico that is also a good idea. Once I have some time I will re-set it up that way also by using 1 Admin user

Comment: This Q&A seems to conflate "TFS Team Project" and "Visual Studio Project". I know of no way to lock a TFS Team Project - short of jumping through the hoops @tvanfosson outlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you still want the project to be available, somebody could just put a lock on the project to prevent check-ins and check-outs. It will remained locked by the user who locks it until either the user unlocks it or their workspace is deleted. An admin can also unlock it using tf.exe.

You can lock a project, branch, folder, or file by right clicking on it and selecting the Lock option from the context menu (note: what you are locking has to exist physically on your drive). [This page](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/000209.html) describes the various types of locks you can place on an item.

For work, I wrote a plug-in to automatically place a check-out lock on production branches once certain criteria are met. The lock is held by the account running the TFS services (in our case, Network Service). Nobody can check-out or check-in files in these branches until somebody uses tf.exe to unlock the branch.

Comment: I 'm sorry for the downvote, but I disagree with what you 're suggesting. If you delete a Team Project from the TFS Admin Console there is no way to revive it. In my understanding it is really deleted.

Comment: You may be right, I thought you were able to restore it using tf undelete. I have removed that from my answer.

Comment: Ok, I removed my downvote. Can you please elaborate on how it would be possible to place this "lock" on the project?

Comment: You got it - I've fleshed out my answer.

Comment: Your answer is now better than mine. +1 (I'm also withdrawing mine - hadn't ever noticed/used the 'lock' option). I consider this answer as the way to go, provided that we only need to block source control operations. If we need to block everything (access to WIs, builds, portal etc), then we should proceed as @tvanfosson suggested in his answer.

Comment: Yup, was playing around with it and that is exactly what I did. Just placed a lock on it. No one can now check it out or in. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

In Team Explorer, right click on the project and bring up Team Project Settings -> Group Membership.  Go through each group, click Properties, and remove all users and groups from each group.  This should prevent anyone who doesn't have a TFS administrator role from being able to check the code out.  It may even prevent TFS administrators from being able to check it out without first adding themselves back to the correct project group.

*I think this will work, but you should try it as I've never actually done it.*

Comment: I don't know about this. I would change security for the groups instead of messing with group and user memberships.

Comment: @AMissico - I favor removing people from roles that they don't need rather than changing the abilities of the roles themselves. YMMV.

Comment: +1 @tvanfosson - now that I understand what he is asking through his comments, your answer is correct. I do this all the time with our other development groups qa, bsa, dba, pm, and so on.